# Migrating Oracle packages to SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, oracle-10g, migration

I'm moving database from Oracle to SQLServer (2012 if that matters). The process of migrating tables/views is more or less straightforward and automated. Triggers are also not an issue since I don't have too many of them.

However, I wonder what is the best practice for moving Oracle packages. As far as I know, SQLServer doesn't have anything similar. My idea is to map each package to SQLServer schema (thus, for instance, I'll have 'package1' , 'package2', etc schemas in SQLServer, each of them has no tables, just functions/procedures/types). I believe it will preserve original purpose of packages and at the same time reduce number of changes required on application side.

Does it make sense or I'm on a wrong way?

Thank you.

Comment: When migrating the triggers, don't forget that SQL Server doesn't have row level triggers, only statement level triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770300/since-sql-server-doesnt-have-packages-what-do-programmers-do-to-get-around-it/)  on the subject. Your idea of mapping Oracle packages to schemas in SQL Server is the approach deemed most directly analogous.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. This is more of a comment than an answer, unless you can provide more than just "that makes sense". Maybe surmise what the SO link your provided speaks about?

Comment: Agreed and edited. Reputation score is insufficient to comment on the original question.